# SQL - Call other SQL files to create multiple tables of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've got a couple of SQL files let's say `tableone1.sql` `tabletwo.sql` and `tablethree.sql`.

I'm developing a web application using `phpmyadmin` and I was wondering what code I could have in a `db.sql` file that would include the three `sql` files to avoid having all my `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements in one huge file.

So then I can import `db.sql` to phpmyadmin and it will create three tables and insert records based on the statements in my three external files.

I hope that makes sense? Apologies for the vague question.

Comment: why dont you run sql files one after the other

Comment: Maybe he has too many and it is pretty boring ;)

Comment: Oh I know I could do them one after the other. Just wondering if there was a more automated way to do it.

Comment: If you're developing a web application, learn how to avoid phpMyAdmin. For your scripts use the command line interface, for interactive work HeidiSQL or Navicat or another decent database editor.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your db.sql file should be something like this:

```
use [dbname];

source path/tableone1.sql;
source path/tableone2.sql;
source path/tableone3.sql;
```

Or you could use the `cat *.sql` command.